# Maldetect + clamAV does not recognise base64 hidden malware

Tags: centos, clamav

I am assigned to do daily malware scans on our Wordpress website to make sure everything is going right. Therefor I have installed Maldetect 1.5 and ClamAV. As I wanted to know if everything is working as it should be, I uploaded an example malware file with with base64 hidden PHP code as copied from https://aw-snap.info/articles/php-examples.php.

However, if I scan these files, Maldetect say "files 4, malware hits 0, cleaned hits 0".

This means that I cannot be sure that Maldetect is actually detecting existing malware. Does anyone here have experience with this and wants to help me?

Cheers

Comment: You should use the plugin  `sucuri-scanner` for wordpress https://nl.wordpress.org/plugins/sucuri-scanner/installation/

Answer (score 1):

Hacker is [encrypting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encryption) those hack tools/shell scripts in order for it to be FUD (Fully Undetected or Fully Undetectable). 
The best you can do is to [submit](https://www.clamav.net/reports/malware) those files to ClamAV and Maldetect so they can add it to their database and successfully detect them next time.

**EDIT**

Instead of you doing those scans every day I highly recommend you to run cron for ClamAV

```
crontab -e #Open cron file

0 4 * * * /usr/local/cpanel/3rdparty/bin/clamscan -ri --remove /home 2>&1 | mail -s "ClamAV Scan Log" your@email.com
```

This will run a scan every day at 4 AM, DELETE infected files and email log to you. Change `/home` to your websites path or scan everything `/`
Also I recommend you to enable monitoring for Maldetect

Answer (score 1):

Posting "malware" examples can be problematic because the A/V vendors tend to flag your site. One method to get around that is to post the code as an image, another way is to "break" the code by adding zero-length spaces &#8203; at key locations.  If you look at the source code for that page the examples are going to be

ev&#8203;al(base&#8203;64_de&#8203;code("ZXJyb3JfcmVwb3J0aW5nKDAp.....

If you wanted to test with any of those examples you would have to clean them up.

No idea why the A/V vendors flag those examples since they are not gone to execute in a browser but that is another story.